# Range-input with two Inputs can be dragged over each other

Tags: javascript, html, sass

I am trying to create a range-input with a maximum and minimum input.
I habe achived this so far:

HTML

```
<div class="zimmer__price">
 <input type="range" min="200" max="500" step="50" value="50" id="lower">
 <input type="range" min="200" max="500" step="50" value="500" id="upper">
</div>
```

JS:

```
upperSlider.oninput = () => {
  lowerVal = parseInt(lowerSlider.value, 10);
  upperVal = parseInt(upperSlider.value, 10);

  currentPriceRange[1] = upperVal;
  currentPriceRange[0] = lowerVal;
};

lowerSlider.oninput = () => {
  lowerVal = parseInt(lowerSlider.value, 10);
  upperVal = parseInt(upperSlider.value, 10);

  currentPriceRange[1] = upperVal;
  currentPriceRange[0] = lowerVal;
};
```

My problem is, that you can drag the minimum input over the maximum and vise versa. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. You need to check the value of the other input and subtract or add to the value.

HTML

```
<div class="zimmer__price">
 <input type="range" min="200" max="500" step="50" value="50" id="lower">
 <input type="range" min="200" max="500" step="50" value="500" id="upper">
</div>
```

JS:

```
upperSlider.oninput = () => {
  lowerVal = parseInt(lowerSlider.value, 10);
  upperVal = parseInt(upperSlider.value, 10);

  if (upperVal < lowerVal + 50) {
    lowerSlider.value = upperVal - 50;
  }
  currentPriceRange[1] = upperVal;
  currentPriceRange[0] = lowerVal;
};

lowerSlider.oninput = () => {
  lowerVal = parseInt(lowerSlider.value, 10);
  upperVal = parseInt(upperSlider.value, 10);

  if (lowerVal > upperVal - 50) {
    upperSlider.value = lowerVal + 50;
  }
  currentPriceRange[1] = upperVal;
  currentPriceRange[0] = lowerVal;
};
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I also improved the code, to automatically take the step of the input to check the valuesteps.